# Perturbation Theory on Finite Domains

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

In [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tV-xIhP7VU8) (from 27.00 - 50.00, which you don't need to watch!) a guy shows how you can solve the general second order ode $y'' + P(x)y = 0$ using perturbation theory. However he points out that the domain must be finite in order for this to work, I'm wondering how you would phrase a question like this or how you would know when you are working with an infinite domain etc...? If I was just given $y'' + x^2y = 0$ & asked to solve it using perturbation theory I wouldn't know if I was getting into trouble about finite or infinite domains, how do I re-phrase the question so that it makes sense? Thanks for your time.

Comment: You should read about the [WKB approximation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WKB_approximation). A great treatise on the asymptotics of $y'' + p(x) y = 0$ can be found in chapter 6 of Olver's _Asymptotics and Special Functions_.